# How to understand `if [ ! -f $R_C_S_L/j_r_d* ] ...` in unix?

Tags: linux, unix, ksh

Please tell me how to debug like the below statements in Unix.
How to understand what the below code is doing, step by step.

```
if [ ! -f $R_C_S_L/j_r_d* ]
    then
echo 0>$R_C_S_L/j_r_d
fi
```

Comment: Do you have a variable `R_C_S_L` in your environment or defined above in the script? This is simply 'if no files match this path then create an empty file' but we've no context to know which path that is. Hopefully someone can also point you at the man pages that explain this (bash? test?)

Comment: Hi Rup, R_C_S_L is a parameter exported from the environement.How do you understood this statement as "'if no files match this path then create an empty file" please tell me in unix where we can find if[ ! -f ...] and statements like these? Thank you for answering.

Comment: Note that you'll get an error message from `[` if the wildcard matches more than one file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you read it just from left to right:

```
 if [ ! -f $R_C_S_L/j_r_d* ]
```

I guess  `if` and `[` is clear?

```
 man [
```

brings `man test` up, and there we read:

```
NAME
       test - check file types and compare values

SYNOPSIS
       test EXPRESSION
       test

       [ EXPRESSION ]
       [ ]
       [ OPTION
```

and further down:

```
   -f FILE
          FILE exists and is a regular file
```

which file?

```
   $R_C_S_L/j_r_d*
```

is parsed from left, where $ indicates, it is a variable. From writing variables myself, and glueing them together, I know, that it will include only the L, so $R_C_S_L is a variable, then / is the directory delimiter, and j_r_d* is part of a name, with a globbing pattern.

So a directory, referenced by $R_C_S_L, with a file, matching j_r_d* is searched, that's the test, and ! is the negation, so if the test fails, the inner part is done.

```
 echo 0 > $R_C_S_L/j_r_d
```

writes a 0 to the shortest file, matching above pattern, if no such file exists.

Answer (score 4):

- `[` and `]` surround the predicate.
- `!` is a NOT predicate, negating whatever is between brackets from true to false.
- `-f` is a predicate, 'does the file exist?'
- `$R_C_S_L` is a variable defined elsewhere.
- `*` is a wildcard.
- `then` starts the if block.
- `fi` ends the if block.
- `echo {stuff}` prints stuff to the screen.
- `echo {stuff} > {file}` redirects it to a file.

The above statement could be thus translated:

"If there is a file that exists which is in the directory $R_C_S_L and starts with the letters j_r_d, then write '0' to the file `j_r_d` in the `$R_C_S_L` directory."

see `$ man bash`.

Comment: if there is `no` such file, you meant. :)

Comment: Yes I also understood like that ,but nice explaination thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It is an if/then statment...

```
if [ I_AM_TRUE ]
then
   DO_ME
fi
```

The `then` is sort of like an opening bracket, the `fi` is sort of like a closing bracket.

`-f FILENAME` is TRUE when FILENAME is a file and
putting a ! in front of that expression flips the truth value ...

so `! -f FILENAME` is TRUE when FILENAME is not a file

`echo` prints out stuff, while the symbol `>` takes that stuff and re-directs it somewhere else.  The value of a VAR is gotten by typing `$VAR`...

lastly, the * is a wildcard, so it will match everything (including nothing!)

So it looks like you check if a particular file prefix is in use, and if it is not, then you create the file and put a zero in it.

For a more complete list of things you can test for inside an if/then statement check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_(Unix) or as said above type `man test` at the prompt.  That would be the man-ly way to do it.